# Does requiring normalization block Curry's Paradox?

Tags: logic

Take the following rules of inference;

(ID) $\frac{}{X \vdash X} \hspace{1cm}$ (EQ) $\frac{\vdash X \hspace{1cm}  X = Y}{\vdash Y}$

(MP) $\frac{\vdash X \rightarrow Y \hspace{1cm} \vdash X}{\vdash Y} \hspace{1cm}$ (AB) $\frac{X \vdash Y}{\vdash X \rightarrow Y}$

We can easily produce Curry's paradox by defining a $C = C \rightarrow Y$ and deriving (Sorry, I can't figure out the Mathjax for this)

----------------- (ID)
C ⊢ C  $\hspace{1cm}$    C ⊢ C
----------------------- (EQ)
C ⊢ C  $\hspace{1cm}$   C ⊢ C → Y
----------- (MP)
C ⊢ Y
--------- (AB)
⊢ C → Y
---------------- (EQ)
⊢ C  $\hspace{1cm}$   ⊢ C → Y
---------------- (MP)
Y

Usually, this is blocked by weakening what I've called "AB" so that X (and sometimes Y) have to provably be propositions. However, it seems to me that one can instead weaken EQ into something like;

(EQ↓) $$\frac{\vdash X \hspace{1cm}  X \downarrow Z \hspace{1cm} Y \downarrow Z}{\vdash Y}$$

Meaning that substitution can only take place if $X$ and $Y$ normalize to the same term, $Z$. Or weaken ID into something like

(ID↓) $$\frac{X \downarrow X}{X \vdash X}$$

So that we can't initialize a proof without the initial term normalizing. These certainly block off the previous proof since it's impossible to define a $C$ satisfying the appropriate equation which normalizes. But does this block off the paradox in general?

I am concerned with this system of rules in particular as well as some of the weaker Illative Combinatory logic systems, like the ones Curry was originally interested in and the ones presented in "Systems of illative combinatory logic complete for first order propositional and predicate calculus".

Comment: Why are you using $C:=C\to\bot$? $\begin{array}{}
C & \vdash & C\\
C & \vdash & C\to\bot\\
\emptyset & \vdash & C\to(C\to\bot)\\
\emptyset & \vdash & C\to\bot\\
\emptyset & \vdash & C\\
\emptyset & \vdash & \bot
\end{array}$ it leads immediately to weirdness

Comment: It is a standard way of defining a proposition that triggers Curry's paradox. You could use any C = C → Y and the derivation would be the same. See the paper "Bunder's Paradox" by M Caie for an almost identical formulation to the one I gave here, for example. You can also use the Y combinator to define an appropriate C satisfying the same equation. I don't understand what your objection is.

Comment: The standard way I've seen is $X:=X\to Y$, with $Y$ being the conclusion. $C:=C\to\bot$ just goes straight to a contradiction, however you're doing the replacement, which isn't paradoxical. Are you wanting true contradictions? If so then [paraconsistent logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic "Wikipedia article on paraconsistent logic") might be useful to you.

Comment: What I want to know is if requiring normalization in the way I specified blocks any sort of paradoxes in the system I specified. I'm asking literally the question I asked. I'm not insinuating some completely different question about a completely different system.

Comment: I rewrote my question to use your formulation. The question is still the same.